# Android won't load back to portrait layout

Tags: android

I have the below code in the file `activity_fbapp.xml` placed in `layout-port`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".ActivityFBapp" >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Portrait" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Then I have the below code in the file `activity_fbapp.xml` (same file name) placed in `layout-land`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".ActivityFBapp" >
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Landscape" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is what I have in my `Activity`:

```
public class ActivityFBapp extends FragmentActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fbapp);
    }
}
```

I use the emulator to test the app. I place it in portrait mode, press `Ctrl+F11` to change orientation in Landscape, and it works. It loads the landscape layout.

**BUT** when I press `Ctrl+F11` again to revert to portrait, it won't reload the portrait layout.

I can't figure out why. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

Add this line in mainfest:

```
 <activity android:name="Your Activity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: There is no necessity to declare layout for portrait and landscape seperately if you use above configChanges property in your manifest, unless you want different layout design in different orientation.

Comment: I want different layouts in each of the two orientations :)

Comment: Then it would be fine if you setContentView(R.layout.activity_fbapp) inside                                                          public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    
} method too...

Comment: This is just stupid. Something's wrong here. Related to `onConfigurationChanged` ... I've been just playing around with it and it seems it doesn't even enter that method when I change the orientation o.O 'the hell is going on ?! It reenters onCreate, but not the onconfigurationChanged method ... Any ideas? o.O

Comment: No, it never happened like that to me. if everything is correctly placed and declared then definitely it will enter onConfigchanged method and not onCreate.

Comment: I've been testing the app on API level 9 ... I've tried it at 11 at the orientation change works ... o.O

Comment: oh..and I extend `FragmentActivity` not `Activity` ... wonder if that has something to do with it ... o.O

Comment: *sigh* it's stuff like this I'm wasting my time with ... Hei, thanks for your time btw ...I'll keep trying

Answer (score 2):

The names of the folder are not Layout-port or Layout-land the letter should be small
like layout-land,layout-port try may be it work..

Comment: True. They are, I just typed them wrong here in the post. So that's not the source of the problem ...